# Use roman numbers for toc, listoffigures etc. in srcartcl

Tags: table-of-contents, roman-numerals

I am writing an assignment where the TOC, list of tables and list of figures have to be numbered with roman numerals, while the rest should be numbered in Arabic.

I can't find a solution for this without resorting to the book class.

[image: SAMPLE]

Comment: Are you talking about page numbers, i.e. at the bottom of the page? If so, just use
`\pagenumbering{roman}` and `\pagenumbering{arabic}` as appropriate. If not, please clarify.

Comment: Yes, but the method with pagenumbering doesn't work for some reason. Added image for clarification.

Comment: The method with `\pagenumbering` should work. If it doesn't, then there is something else in your code which is interfering. However, without seeing the code it's anybody's guess what. Please provide a full [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/82917) which reproduces the issue, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE... What about `\frontmatter` tag? Which will take care of page numbers by auto...Please post your `MWE` to get better suggestion...

Comment: @MadyYuvi `\frontmatter `is defined in `scrbook`, not `scrartcl`. That's precisely the point of the question.

Comment: @campa Oops, sorry I've not used `scrartcl` frequently....